# browser-sync serving files from specific directory not working

Tags: localhost, browser-sync, web-development-server

I am using browser-sync and want to serve files from /src directory. To make this happen I am using browser-sync configuration `server: "src"`. Unfortunately I get *Cannot GET /* instead of my index.html.

Configuration is being successfully used by browser-sync because I can change serving port and it works.

Any ideas? Maybe I am using wrong configuration for this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not.